# notification icon color issue

Tags: android, mobile, notifications, icons

I have an issue with notification in my Android app :
On Samsung devices (Android 7), my icon works in notification bar and when I show the notification menu :

[Notification bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bbor.jpg)

[Notification menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9t5L.jpg)

But on other device, like Google Nexus 5 or 5x (Android 6 and 7) (or with the android studio emulator), I just have the icon "form" like this :

[Emulator Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZN2.png)

Is it possible to have default colored icon on all device or should I use only transparent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour since lollipop or marshmallow

For this cases try to use an icon with transparent regions

put it in separate folder e.g. `drawable-v21`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using a white icon without background. Dimming now works and setColor works on all the devices correctly.

Thanks V. Kalyuzhnyu